# Extracting a single object as an object rather than as an array with one object, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, and would like to extract just one object, but then manipulate that object later as an object rather than an array with one object in it. My array of objects is:

```
  var holidayList = [
    {name: "CHRISTMAS",
    month: 11,
    modifier: 5},{...},{...},
  ]
```

To extract for example the object with `name: "CHRISTMAS"` I use filter:

```
  var holidayIn = "CHRISTMAS";
  var toDoHoliday = holidayList.filter(function(x){
    return x.name === holidayIn;
  });
```

Now if I `console.log(toDoHoliday);` I get `[{name: "CHRISTMAS", month: 11, modifier: 5}]` an array with one object in it. I tried using map:

```
  var toDoHoliday = holidayList.filter(function(x){
    return x.name === holidayIn;
  }).map(function(element){
    return {name: element.name};
  });
```

Which returns `toDoHoliday` as `[{name: "CHRISTMAS"}]`, so still an array with one object in it.

How can I get my object as just an object, so I can do things later like `toDoHoliday.name` and so on?

Comment: You could just `pop` the element, or use `find` instead of `filter` (although it's an ES6 feature).

Comment: Use `[0]` to select item at index `0` of returned array

Comment: `var toDoHoliday = holidayList.filter(function(x){ ... })[0];`
This makes toDoHoliday an object instead of an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[n]` notation to select item at index `n` from array of objects returned by `.filter()`

```
  var holidayIn = "CHRISTMAS";
  var toDoHoliday = holidayList.filter(function(x){
    return x.name === holidayIn;
  });
  console.log(toDoHoliday[0].name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just did a `toDoHoliday = toDoHoliday[0]` to convert it, and it worked. Is that really good behavior though? I feel like I'm... cheating somehow

Comment: @komali_2 Could substitute single variable declaration `var toDoHoliday = holidayList.filter(function(x){
    return x.name === holidayIn;
  })[0]` for defining `toDoHoliday` twice at `toDoHoliday = toDoHoliday[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The `find()` method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

```
var toDoHoliday = holidayList.find(function(x){
  return x.name === holidayIn;
});
```

**Note:** Not all browsers support it yet, so will need to polyfill it if the code runs in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with a 3rd party library, you can't go past lodash (one of the most useful things since sliced bread) and, in your particular case, the [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) function.

From the docs:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// → object for 'barney'

// using the `_.matches` iteratee shorthand
_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// → object for 'pebbles'

// using the `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand
_.find(users, ['active', false]);
// → object for 'fred'

// using the `_.property` iteratee shorthand
_.find(users, 'active');
// → object for 'barney'
```

It is, of course, useful for so many other things beyond simple `_.find`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var holidayIn = "CHRISTMAS";
var toDoHoliday = null; // Will remain as this if not found

for ( var i = 0; i < holidayList.length; i++ ){
  if ( holidayList[i].name === holidayIn ){
    toDoHoliday = holidayList[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: a. Use `for` to iterate over an array. b. Stop looping after you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to iterate your array first.
So, enter code here

```
var cnt = holidayList.length();  
for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++){  
   var newObject = holidayList[$i]; 
   //And now you can do newObject.name etc  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by using [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
      var holidayIn = "CHRISTMAS";                                                               
      var holidayList = [       
         {name: "CHRISTMAS" , month: 11, modifier: 5},
         {name: "CHRISTMAS1", month: 12, modifier: 65},
         {name: "CHRISTMAS2", month: 144,modifier: 77},
       ]                                                                                         
     let [toDoHoliday] = holidayList.filter((x)=>{     
       return x.name === holidayIn                     
     })                                                                                              
     console.log(toDoHoliday) 
     console.log(toDoHoliday.name)
```

```
[![destructuring][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by using [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
      var holidayIn = "CHRISTMAS";                                                               
      var holidayList = [       
         {name: "CHRISTMAS" , month: 11, modifier: 5},
         {name: "CHRISTMAS1", month: 12, modifier: 65},
         {name: "CHRISTMAS2", month: 144,modifier: 77},
       ]                                                                                         
     let [toDoHoliday] = holidayList.filter((x)=>{     
       return x.name === holidayIn                     
     })                                                                                              
     console.log(toDoHoliday) 
     console.log(toDoHoliday.name)
```